# Dual Boot Ubuntu with a MacBook Pro 2018 - partitions not showing on installation

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, mac

So I have followed the following tutorial on installing Ubuntu on a MacBook Pro 2018.

https://www.lifewire.com/dual-boot-linux-and-mac-os-4125733

The issue is when I have to setup the partitions on the ubuntu installation the drives do not show up and when I click the + icon the installation freezes along with any other button such as install now. Any ideas why this happening? Thanks.

Comment: Post to your question the output from the Terminal application command `diskutil list`. Also, what is the name of the ISO file you downloaded from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple latest products (MBP 2018, iMac Pro) are equipped with the T2 chip which control some of the internal components, including the SSD.
No driver has been released for Linux, so until then, **it is not possible** to install Ubuntu on the internal SSD.

You can still install it on an external drive or in a VM.

Comment: That is really sad to hear. Damn them!